# WSO2 API manager 1.6 - adding API error - Postgresql

Tags: wso2

On a brand new install against a postgresql database, when trying to create new API's via the publisher, I receive this error: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Cannot commit when autoCommit is enabled.

I've added this to the end of my jdbc url: ?autoReconnect=true&relaxAutoCommit=true , but that does not seem to work.

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes AutoCommit won't work with postgres. Just modify the datasource definition as follows,

```
<datasource>
        <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
        <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
        <jndiConfig>
            <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
        </jndiConfig>
        <definition type="RDBMS">
            <configuration>
                <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/CARBON_DB</url>
        <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit> 
                <username>postgres</username>
                <password>postgres</password>
                <driverClassName>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClassName>
                <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
            </configuration>
        </definition>
    </datasource>
```